# GET table's description in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to get simply the `MS_Description` for the table

For now I have it only for columns:

```
select 
    sc.name, 
    sep.value [Description]
from sys.tables st
inner join sys.columns sc on st.object_id = sc.object_id
left join sys.extended_properties sep on st.object_id = sep.major_id
                                     and sc.column_id = sep.minor_id
                                     and sep.name = 'MS_Description'
where st.name =@TableName
```

I also have @TableName as Parameter there
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this - basically use the `minor_id = 0` to get the table's description (not any columns):

```
SELECT 
    t.Name, 
    sep.* 
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN 
    sys.extended_properties sep ON t.object_id = sep.major_id
where 
    sep.Name = 'MS_Description'
    AND sep.minor_id = 0    -- not any column - but the table's description
```

Comment: perfect thís is what i want... The other question was for any columns in one Table but i only wanted the Table Descrition